# How to create a popup window in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to create a popup window in a JavaFX application. Give me some ideas.

[image]

When I click on *Check* button it opens the popup window.
How to do it?

Comment: Sorry I cant format this code with newline(s) in a comment - but here you go. This will create a new Window: `BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
                          Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 600);
                          Stage stage = new Stage();
                          stage.setScene(scene);
                          stage.setTitle("Cool Window");
                          stage.show();`

Answer (score 44):

You can either create a new `Stage`, add your controls into it or if you require the POPUP as `Dialog` box, then you may consider using [DialogsFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/javajungle/entry/dialogfx_a_new_approach_to) or [ControlsFX](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.html)(Requires JavaFX8)

For creating a new Stage, you can use the following snippet

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Open Dialog");
    btn.setOnAction(
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
                VBox dialogVbox = new VBox(20);
                dialogVbox.getChildren().add(new Text("This is a Dialog"));
                Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogVbox, 300, 200);
                dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
                dialog.show();
            }
         });
    }
```

If you don't want it to be `modal` (block other windows), use:

```
dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
```

Comment: What do I need to import in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 6):

The Popup class might be better than the Stage class, depending on what you want.  Stage is either modal (you can't click on anything else in your app) or it vanishes if you click elsewhere in your app (because it's a separate window).  Popup stays on top but is not modal.

See this [Popup Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527895/popup-window-with-table-view-in-javafx-2-0) example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [ControlsFx Popover control](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).

---

```
import org.controlsfx.control.PopOver;
import org.controlsfx.control.PopOver.ArrowLocation;

private PopOver item;

final Scene scene = addItemButton.getScene();

final Point2D windowCoord = new Point2D(scene.getWindow()
        .getX(), scene.getWindow().getY());

final Point2D sceneCoord = new Point2D(scene.getX(), scene.
                getY());

final Point2D nodeCoord = addItemButton.localToScene(0.0,
                        0.0);
final double clickX = Math.round(windowCoord.getX()
    + sceneCoord.getY() + nodeCoord.getX());

final double clickY = Math.round(windowCoord.getY()
        + sceneCoord.getY() + nodeCoord.getY());
item.setContentNode(addItemScreen);
item.setArrowLocation(ArrowLocation.BOTTOM_LEFT);
item.setCornerRadius(4);                            
item.setDetachedTitle("Add New Item");
item.show(addItemButton.getParent(), clickX, clickY);
```

---

This is only an example but a PopOver sounds like it could accomplish what you want. Check out the [documentation](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.html) for more info.

**Important note: ControlsFX will only work on JavaFX 8.0 b118 or later.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jfxmessagebox (http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/jfxmessagebox/) if you are looking for very simple dialog popups.