# Call Javascript Popup in java program

Tags: java, popupwindow, nashorn

I'm try show Popup in java program(web).

I try ScriptEngine with javascript, nashorn but fail. Because alert,confirm, prompt is not method of js.

Code in java program:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("script.js"));

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
invocable.invokeFunction("openPopup", "ABC XYZ");
```

and in script.js:

```
function openPopup(str){
    alert(str);
}
```

Run it, error show:

> "alert" is undefined

Comment: You need to provide more information. In the current state it is totally unclear what you are asking. I.e. what is the problem? What are you trying to do? What technologies are you using? Do you have some code that you can show us? Are we able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Show us your code. Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856279/call-external-javascript-functions-from-java-code)?

Comment: Nashhorn isn't running in the browser, is it?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for care. I updated question.

Comment: @M.leRutte yes! alert is function of window

Comment: Nashorn is a way to run javascript inside the JVM, there are no alert() or popup boxes, these are browser provided functionalities.

Comment: @M.leRutte, so We have no solution for this case ?

Comment: Of course there is, but you have to learn more about Java and the scripting engine.

Comment: You can do this in two parts. Do you have any windows showing? eg are you using swing or javafx? Then it is just a matter of creating a popup with that tool kit.

Comment: @matt I build website, I will research more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Opening a **JavaScript popup** in Java is **not possible**. The JavaScript Engine **Nashorn** does not provide this method. It usually is a functionality provided by **browsers**.

That is also why you are getting:

> "alert" is undefined

---

### Solution

You can open popup windows with different tools in **Java**, for example **Swing** or **JavaFX**. Those are tools with which you can create programs with **graphical user interfaces** (GUI), i.e. *that have windows*.

Here is an [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) by Oracle on how to create dialogs with **Swing**.

The relevant method for creating *just a simple popup* is:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello world!");
```

Where `frame` is a reference to the *window* which should be the parent of this popup. However you can simply pass `null` for a **quick and dirty popup**:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello world!");
```

Just use the above code, import the `JOptionPane` and it should work:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

The class has more interesting methods to check out, like input dialogs. Here is its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

---

The **JavaFX** solution is a bit more complicated as it requires you to setup the frame and handle several events.

You may check out this other question [SO: Popup window with table view in JavaFX 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527895/popup-window-with-table-view-in-javafx-2-0). It uses the designated class `Popup` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html)).

Comment: May be I can try it in web app ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You can not execute Java in a browser. What framework are you talking of?

Comment: Thanks for your help.